# Django Rest Framework auto increment primary key value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to using the DRF so I apologize if this is a trivial question but I've had no luck finding an answer thus far.

I'm using DRF along with Angularjs to create a single page application. When I make posts to my API I get this error to create a new `Task` object: `task_id: [This field is required.]` `task_id` is my primary key on this object. How can I make it so that it gets incremented automatically like it would on a Django Model Form?

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):         

    class Meta:                                                      
        model = Task                                       
        fields = ('route', 'date', 'task_id', )                    

class AddTask(generics.CreateAPIView):          
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer                                                    

    def get(self, request, format=None):                  
        response = {}                                     

        response['form'] = TaskForm().as_p()    

        return Response(response)
```

Comment: Are you using task_id in your application page? If not, then remove it from the serializer and DRF will automatically take care of this for you

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. That did it. Previously I didn't explicitly assign any fields to `fields` in my Meta class and I was getting that error. I suppose that is because I have a unique primary key value `task_id` rather then `id`.

Comment: cool..i ll add the answer then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using `task_id` in your application page? If not, then remove it from the serializer and DRF will automatically take care of this for you.

Something like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):         

    class Meta:                                                      
        model = Task                                       
        fields = ('route', 'date',)
```

Comment: how to update through this serializer, if I didn't mention 'id' as a field?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to serialize an update queryset?

Comment: I want to make INSERT's and UPDATE's into table with auto-increment pk. If I don't include 'id' field as you suggest then how update should work?

Comment: Since 'id' is an autofield in this scenario, django automatically creates an id(which will be serial) upon insert. During an update operation, we need to get a record and use the update( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once ) command as mentioned here in the link.

Comment: You need to define the auto-increment field in your 'Task model', the serializer is for validating. Serializers are for validating incoming data and converting JSON to python data formats that we can use with create, retrieving, updating, and deleting information in our tables(models). Auto-incremented fields are not incoming data, but rather, implemented by Django automatically within a create method.