# Django rest framework serializer: how to update table with auto_increment pk?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a table with auto increment primary key. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089485/django-rest-framework-auto-increment-primary-key-value) says that I just shouldn't place it in field list. But how to update a record then? If I pass 'id' field to serializer, it ignores it

Comment: Have you tried to assign each resource to unique url (eg. 'api/resources/{id}' )?
So if you make PUT/PATCH request to this url, DRF will know which recorde should be updated
I believe this is the default behavior if ypu are using DRF default viewsets or views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you send your id. If you have it in your url, you need to either rename it as *pk* or redefine the *lookup_field* on your view.

From the DRF source code:

```
class GenericAPIView(views.APIView):
    ...

    # If you want to use object lookups other than pk, set this attribute.
    # For more complex lookup requirements override `get_object()`.
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

If you only send it in your json (or whatever you are using), you might have to override the `.get_object()` method on your view.